# -bash: yum: command not found

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I have one server with Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 3) installed. And I tried to add the online repo using this link:

[Centos Wiki: RPMForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge)

And everything goes smooth. But when I tried to install any package it replies:

```
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# yum -v install httpd
-bash: yum: command not found
```

There are some repos in `/etc/yum.repo.d/`:

```
mirrors-rpmforge  mirrors-rpmforge-extras  mirrors-rpmforge-testing  rpmforge.repo
```

The content of `rpmforge.repo` is:

```
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# cat rpmforge.repo
### Name: RPMforge RPM Repository for RHEL 4 - dag
### URL: http://rpmforge.net/
[rpmforge]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/$basearch/rpmforge
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/mirrors-rpmforge
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-extras]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - extras
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/$basearch/extras
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
enabled = 0
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-testing]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - testing
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/$basearch/testing
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
enabled = 0
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1
```

## Command Results

```
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# yum
-bash: yum: command not found
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# which yum
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin)
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# rpm -q yum
package yum is not installed
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# find /bin/ /usr/bin -name yum
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# find /bin/ /usr/bin -name yum*
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# ls -l /etc/yum.comf
ls: /etc/yum.comf: No such file or directory
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# ls -l /etc/yum.conf
ls: /etc/yum.conf: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you give the exact terminal output?

Comment: I added the information in Question Section

Comment: could you please provide output of following commands: `type yum` ; `which yum` ; `echo $PATH` ; `rpm -q yum` ; `find /bin /usr/bin -name yum`

Comment: I have added the info in Question under Command Results. Seems like yum is not installed

Comment: So you have to install it, and everything will be fine :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After simple checks I've asked you in answer comment:

```
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# yum
-bash: yum: command not found
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# which yum
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin)
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
[root@Backup yum.repos.d]# rpm -q yum
package yum is not installed
```

we can verify that you don't have yum installed in your system.

Please install it via `rpm` and you'll be able to launch it.

Comment: Why this happen ?      `[root@cpanel1 ~]# passwd
-bash: passwd: command not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]# passwd
-bash: passwd: command not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]# yum update
-bash: yum: command not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]# type yum
-bash: type: yum: not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]# which yum
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (:/root/bin)
[root@cpanel1 ~]# echo $PATH
:/root/bin
[root@cpanel1 ~]# rpm -q yum
-bash: rpm: command not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]# find /bin /usr/bin -name yum
-bash: find: command not found
[root@cpanel1 ~]#`

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org).
2. Find the yum rpm package for your rhel version and architecture (x86 or x86_64).
3. Download the rpm package.
4. Install with `su -c 'rpm -i ~/Downloads/*.rpm` or with your graphical package manager.

Answer (score 0):

They yum package is not installed by default in RHEL4, because it appeared later. You can installed it or use up2date command to install software.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So this is the reason. I never used rhel4 before so i had no idea about it. I started to learn from rhel5