# No package manager on Red Hat

Tags: rhel, package-management

Just logged into a server my friend is using to host his website, so I can install some packages. I use Ubuntu myself, so I tried using `apt-get` out of habit, but the command was not found. Using `cat /proc/version` gave the following:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-773.26.1.lve1.4.35.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
```

so I then tried using `yum`, but once again the command was not found. Trying `rpm` gives the same result. What can I do now?

Comment: Did you try asking the hosting service your friend is presumably paying for the hosting? Or checking on their site for FAQs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not yet, but that will be the next step. I thought maybe someone on here would know an easy / quick solution, because it normally takes  a while for them to answer.

Comment: Possibly related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352520/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do would probably be to submit a support ticket with your hosting provided. They could have done all sorts of things that would cause your environment to differ from a standard Red Hat environment. That said, here's some stuff you could try.

It's possible that the `yum` directory just isn't your `PATH`. Since `yum` is intended to be used by the system administrator it might make sense for it to be in the path for the `root` user but not for a regular user. So the first thing to try would be running `yum` as root, e.g.:

```bsh
sudo yum
```

If that doesn't work then try enumerating the directories in your `PATH`:

```bsh
(IFS=:; for d in ${PATH}; do echo $d; done)
```

For a regular user I get something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/home/username/.local/bin
/home/username/bin
```

And also for the `root` user's path:

```bsh
sudo bash -c 'IFS=:; for d in ${PATH}; do echo $d; done'
```

And here is what I get for my `root` user:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

You can check your output against these to see if any directories are missing.

There are also a couple of commands you could use to search the file-system. If you have `locate` installed you could use that:

```bsh
updatedb
locate yum
```

Otherwise, and if the file-system isn't too big, you could use `find` and not pull any punches (this is probably overkill):

```bsh
sudo find / -name yum
```

The same thing goes for the `rpm` command.

Here are the paths for my `yum` and `rpm` commands:

```bsh
user@host:~$ type -a yum
yum is /bin/yum
yum is /usr/bin/yum

user@host:~$ type -a rpm
rpm is /bin/rpm
rpm is /usr/bin/rpm
```

If none of that turns anything up then it would seem likely that your hosting provider just doesn't have it installed.

Here is a related link that you might want to skim through:

[-bash: yum: command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76432/bash-yum-command-not-found)